# What does the border color mean in Little Inferno item catalog?

Tags: little-inferno

When I open any item catalog in [Little Inferno](http://tomorrowcorporation.com/littleinferno), some items have a different border color. I can see a black border, a silver border and a gold border. What do they mean?

[image: Item catalog, showing 20 items]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [InfernoFans](http://infernofans.com/catalog/easter-eggs):

> The first time you buy an item, the border turns silver. The second time, it turns dark grey. The third time it turns gold.
>
> If you get gold borders on every item on a catalog, that catalog gets a star.
>
> If you get a star on every catalog - i.e. you have bought every single item three times - something happens.

According to [Gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/677349-little-inferno/65082262), that special thing is that

> when you have a golden frame around all 140 items (7 Stars), you'll get an additional letter from miss Nancy. There's no item in that letter, though.

[Also](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221260/discussions/0/846946588494573138/), silver and black bordered items require time to restock but gold-bordered items are always in stock.